# How do I alter a time value to include a leading zero using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been given an XML file which is populated with elements including a "start_time" event which does not add a leading zero to time structure.

E.g. 
"12:00" = OK 
"21:00" = OK 
"9:00" = NOT OK

I need the XML "start_time" to be consistent so that I can perform a sort on those attributes. I.e. I need the time to always be 4-digits in length (5 if you count the colon separator). E.g. "09:00" when a leading zero is added.

Can anybody suggest how I can go about this? I am completely new to XSL and I've come up with nothing so far.

The XML looks like the following:

```
<ArrayOfEvent>
 <Event>
  <category_name>Academic</category_name>
  <event_title>Test (Paper one)</event_title>
  <allday>false</allday>
  <start_time>12:52</start_time>
  <start_date>04/10/2012</start_date>
  <end_time>9:00</end_time>
  <end_date>04/10/2012</end_date>
 </Event>

 <Event>
  <category_name>Academic</category_name>
  <event_title>Test (Paper two)</event_title>
  <allday>false</allday>
  <start_time>2:00</start_time>
  <start_date>10/10/2012</start_date>
  <end_time>9:00</end_time>
  <end_date>10/10/2012</end_date>
 </Event>

 <Event>
  <category_name>Academic</category_name>
  <event_title>Prize Giving</event_title>
  <allday>false</allday>
  <start_time>22:31</start_time>
  <start_date>23/09/2013</start_date>
  <end_time>9:00</end_time>
  <end_date>23/09/2013</end_date>
 </Event>
</ArrayOfEvent>
```

Comment: Do you have any XSLT code for us to work from? What have you tried? What hasn't worked? How hasn't it worked?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to add

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(end_time) &lt; 5">0</xsl:if>
```

at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a number using `number(translate($in, ':', '.'))` and then use `format-number($n, '00:00')` in conjunction with a decimal format that uses ":" as the decimal-separator.